# Invalid value for stripe.confirmPayment(): elements should have a mounted Payment Element

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate a Stripe payments page using the React "Elements". I'm following the tutorial from https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-submit-payment and I've gotten to step 5, "Submit the payment to Stripe". My code doesn't look much different from the example, but whenever I try to submit a payment this error:

> Invalid value for stripe.confirmPayment(): elements should have a mounted Payment Element.

Thrown from `stripe.confirmPayment`. I've included the `<Elements/>` and `<PaymentElement/>` on the page, and passed the return value from `useElements()` so I'm really not sure what I'm missing.

---

Here's my checkout form:

```
function StripeCheckoutForm({paymentIntent,booking}: StripeCheckoutFormProps) {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const [confirming,setConfirming] = useState(false)

    const handleSubmit = async (ev: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        ev.preventDefault();

        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            notifyWarning("Still loading. Please wait a few seconds and then try again.");
            return;
        }

        setConfirming(true)
        try {
            const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
                //`Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
                elements,
                confirmParams: {
                    return_url: resolveRoute('customerPaymentReceived',{key:booking.key}),
                },
            })
            if(error) {
                notifyError(error.message)
                setConfirming(false)
            }
        } catch(error) {
            setConfirming(false)
            if(error?.message) {
                notifyError(error.message)  // <-- error shown here
            } else {
                notifyError("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <PaymentElement/>
            <BlockSpacer height="1rem"/>
            <ActionButton disabled={!stripe || !elements || confirming} type="submit" className="btn-phone btn-fullwidth">Pay {paymentIntent.amountFormatted}</ActionButton>
        </form>
    )
}
```

And that form is inside this component, similar to the example shown in step 4:

```
import {Elements as StripeElements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {useStripe, useElements, PaymentElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

function StripePaymentForm({stripeAccountId,paymentIntent,booking}: StripePaymentFormProps) {
    const options = {
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.clientSecret,
        loader: 'always',
    }
    return (
        <StripeElements stripe={getStripeConnect(stripeAccountId)} options={options}>
            <StripeCheckoutForm paymentIntent={paymentIntent} booking={booking}/>
        </StripeElements>
    )
}
```

The only thing I can see that's different is that I'm using a Connect account, so I'm passing in account ID in when I load Stripe. `getStripeConnect` is basically

```
loadStripe(STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY, {stripeAccount: CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID})
```

---

You can see the React component tree here if it helps:

[image]

What am I missing?

---

I'm guessing this stems from `useElements()` is not finding any elements:

[image]

But I still don't know why.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have a similar issue myself.

Comment: @RoughChop See the other answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/72354497/65387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's a recent bug in react-stripe-js:

https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/issues/296

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you so much! Just had to put `useMemo()` around `options`

Comment: none of the suggestions on that github issue are working for me 

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue is that during the stripe request `stripe.confirmPayment`, the component that has the `Elements` component must be being rendered on page.

If you remove this component from the DOM to show a loading animation during the request, for example, the error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `loadStripe()` promise isn't resolved at the time it is passed to the Elements provider, thus useElements returns null. Either load it earlier or await it and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: `useElements()` isn't returning null, I have a `if(!elements)` check

Answer (score 0):

Hi @mapen I was also facing the same problem,
So the problem is with the return URL I think

```
 return_url: resolveRoute('customerPaymentReceived',{key:booking.key}),
            },
        })
```

Your Return URL is not giving the correct amount of time for Stripe confirmpayment to send the card details to the Stripe server so you are getting that error I guess
So try to hard code the URL(eg: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" (give the exact path where it should return after successful payment) )  and see if it works for you or not...

Comment: If you're implying that `resolveRoute` is asynchronous, it's not. It's resolves to a valid URL immediately.